# I am Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS while NSURLREQUEST

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS while NSURLREQUEST.
I am giving pdf url from server to to webview through AppDelegate_iPhone's currentBookPressed.
please can anyone tell what is the problem ...
Code:-

```
@class AppDelegate_iPhone;
@interface PdfShowViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate> {

    UIWebView *pdfWebview;
    AppDelegate_iPhone *appDelegate;
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *myIndicator;
    IBOutlet UIProgressView *progress;

    NSURLRequest* DownloadRequest;
    NSURLConnection* DownloadConnection;

    long long bytesReceived;
    long long expectedBytes;

}


@property (nonatomic,retain) UIWebView *pdfWebview;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *myIndicator;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progress;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableData *receivedData;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSURLRequest* DownloadRequest;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSURLConnection* DownloadConnection;

-(IBAction)onTapBack;

@end


#import "PdfShowViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate_iPhone.h"

@implementation PdfShowViewController

@synthesize pdfWebview,myIndicator,progress,receivedData,DownloadRequest,DownloadConnection;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [receivedData appendData:data];

    unsigned char byteBuffer[[receivedData length]];
    [receivedData getBytes:byteBuffer];
    NSLog(@"Data === %ld",receivedData);

    NSInteger receivedLen = [data length];
    bytesReceived = (bytesReceived + receivedLen);
    NSLog(@"received Bytes ==  %f",bytesReceived);

    if(expectedBytes != NSURLResponseUnknownLength) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Expected Bytes in if ==  %f",expectedBytes);
        NSLog(@"received Bytes in if ==  %f",bytesReceived);

        float value = ((float) (bytesReceived *100/expectedBytes))/100;
        NSLog(@"Value ==  %f",value);
        progress.progress=value;
    }

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    //[connection release];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    expectedBytes = [response expectedContentLength];
    NSLog(@"%f",expectedBytes);

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    [myIndicator stopAnimating];
    [myIndicator removeFromSuperview];

    pdfWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 420)];
    [pdfWebview setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];   
    [pdfWebview setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [pdfWebview setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];

    [pdfWebview loadRequest:DownloadRequest];

    [self.view addSubview:pdfWebview];

    //[connection release];


}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    appDelegate = (AppDelegate_iPhone *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    myIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    myIndicator.center = self.view.center;  
    myIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:myIndicator];
    [myIndicator startAnimating];

    //receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.currentBookPressed);
    NSString * urlString = [appDelegate.currentBookPressed stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",urlString);

    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSLog(@"%@",targetURL);

// Here comes Acception

    DownloadRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:targetURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:120.0];
    DownloadConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:DownloadRequest delegate:self];

    if (DownloadConnection) {
        receivedData = [[[NSMutableData data]initWithLength:0]retain];
    }

}

// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
-(IBAction)onTapBack
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [pdfWebview release];
    [receivedData release];
}


@end
```

Comment: Where is the place that you get the exception?

Comment: i have written in between the code where i am getting... i am getting while Accessing NSURLREQUEST...       this is the pdf link... http://litofinter.es.milfoil.arvixe.com/PDF/1211025183_test.pdf

Comment: Acception is :--- *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c776e0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace line

```
DownloadRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:targetURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:120.0];
```

with line

```
DownloadRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:120.0];
```

It is because method `requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:` in first parameter is waiting for object of `NSURL` class. In `targerURL` you have exactly that one.

Moreover in method `[NSURL URLWithString:targetURL]` (if you will need it) you should pass `NSString` as a first parameter, but you are passing `NSURL`.

Comment: Thanks again Nekto... but still it is giving me EXC_BAD_ACCESS , but now at different posi.. :).it is coming at line              [pdfWebview loadRequest:DownloadRequest];

Comment: but i have one more Question i.e. when i load my webview in Portrait mode it is fine in landscape and portrait view... but whenever i load my webview in landscape mode the web view loads in half screen  only (compresses) and when i change the orientation to portrait mode it agian more compresses... what should i do?

Comment: 1. At the end of `viewDidLoad` add line `[DownloadRequest retain];`. 2. Second question please ask in another thread (separate question)

Comment: by the way that [DownloadRequest retain]; is not working... :((

Answer (score 1):

Your problem in this line

```
DownloadRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:targetURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:120.0];
```

The problem in your case arises because parameter for `+ (id)URLWithString:(NSString *)URLString` is `NSString` and you are passing NSURL and method trying to get the length of the supposed string by calling `-length`, which exists for NSString but not for NSURL.

Comment: thanks for your explanation... it was good for me, i resolved that part but now i am getting exception on this line.......... Thanks again Nekto... but still it is giving me EXC_BAD_ACCESS , but now at different posi.. :).it is coming at line              [pdfWebview loadRequest:DownloadRequest];

Comment: put breakpoint in - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection and check value of DownloadRequest.

Comment: but i have one more Question i.e. when i load my webview in Portrait mode it is fine in landscape and portrait view... but whenever i load my webview in landscape mode the web view loads in half screen  only (compresses) and when i change the orientation to portrait mode it agian more compresses... what should i do?